# Width binding in custom DataGrid Header produces error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, width, ivalueconverter

I have created a custom `DataGrid` Header which contains a `TextBlock` for the Text and an `Image`, placed inside a `DockPanel`.
I am binding `TextBlock`'s `Width` to the `ActualWidth` of the `DataGridTextColumn` as follows:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource FitFilterImageToHeaderConverter}}"
```

The simple converter i use is subtracting the width of the `Image` :

```
    public class SubtractConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Subtractor { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return val - Subtractor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but i am getting an annoying binding error.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='-11' BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')`

What am i missing here?

Comment: Seems you are returning a negative value at `return val - Subtractor`, which is not a valid value for the Width property. You should check if the result is >= 0, i.e. `return Math.Max(0, val - Subtractor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value of [`Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to a value less than zero.
But you're setting the value to `-11`. This causes the error.

In your converter you should check if the returned result is equal to zero or greater:

```
...
var result = val - Substractor;
return result > 0 ? result : 0;
```